# How to find the training accuracy using fitcsvm?

Tags: matlab, svm

I would like to find the predicted labels of data point feature vectors while training the classifier, i am using `MDL=fitcsvm(train_data,train_labels)` in matlab the MDL is composed of properties, none of them corresponds to the training accuracy,  Is there any way to find it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply cross validation

```
xval = crossval(Mdl,'KFold',10);
kfoldLoss(xval)
```